# Fill-paragraph should retain "\ " (backslash-space)

Tags: fill-paragraph, markdown-mode

In (Pandoc) markdown `"\ "` means non-breaking space.

When I fill-paragraph, there is a chance that

```
... 50\ cm ...
```

is converted to

```
... 50\
cm ...
```

which means something different.

Is there a (simple) way to make `fill-paragraph` respect `"\ "`?

Comment: Can you just use a no-break space char instead of that markdown, as a workaround?

Comment: Yes, that would also work, and would perhaps be better for my fill-problem, but that character isn't displayed in the terminal `" "` vs `" "` and in Emacs, I find `" "` to be displayed similarly to `"_"` which I use a lot.

Comment: Maybe you could make the no-break-space visible using `(standard-display-ascii ?\240 "NB"))` (or choose any other replacement to your preference).